# How to remove a node from an Elasticsearch cluster at runtime without downtime

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I had five nodes in a cluster and I had to remove two nodes at run time. So how can it be done without affecting the indices?

I had a continuous stream of data coming at nearly 10 Gb/hour which is getting indexed continuously.

Would rebalancing be a help in this?

Comment: why is solr tagged in this question? I guess this is only elasticsearch related question. Please don't use wrong tags. This might mislead users to look into irrevlevant question.

Comment: 10 gigabit/hour or 10 gigabyte/hour?

Answer (score 149):

You can decommission a node by telling the cluster to exclude it from allocation. (From the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-filtering.html))

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
   }
}';echo
```

This will cause Elasticsearch to allocate the shards on that node to the remaining nodes, without the state of the cluster changing to yellow or red (even if you have replication 0).

Once all the shards have been reallocated you can shutdown the node and do whatever you need to do there. Once you're done, include the node for allocation and Elasticsearch will rebalance the shards again.

Comment: Also "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" and "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._id" can be used to decommission by node name and node id. Needed this in a situation when due to incorrect configuration (/etc/hosts & elasticsearch.yml) all nodes got the same (published) IP 127.0.1.1.

Comment: How do I check if it is OK to shut down the decommissioned node?

Comment: You could use `curl -XGET 'http://ES_SERVER:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'`; if there are no nodes relocating, then the excluded node must have been drained and safe to shut down. Another option is to check `curl -XGET 'http://ES_SERVER:9200/_nodes/NODE_NAME/stats/indices?pretty'` to see if there are no documents left on the node.

Comment: Multiple _ip records can be comma separated, ex:

    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2"

Comment: If you have a cluster behind a load balancer, should you remove the node from the load balancer then remove it from routing allocation, or remove it from routing allocation then the load balancer?

Comment: @TomMiller - It doesn't matter. if you take it out of the routing allocation before removing it from the load balancer it'll still handle queries and return results.

Comment: Note that starting from ES6, you need to also specify the content type, e.g.

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
   }
}';echo

Comment: @pudelwudel Updated the answer to use appropriate `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 11):

To remove an Elasticsearch node from the cluster. Just run the following command:

```
curl -XPUT P.P.P.P:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "X.X.X.X"
   }
}';echo
```

Here `P.P.P.P` is the private IP address of the master node. You may also use the `localhost` if Elasticsearch is running on `localhost`. `X.X.X.X` is the private IP address of the node to be removed from the cluster.

This command will give `acknowledgement` `true` if the node is accepted to be removed and the data relocation will start. Check if the data relocation is over and the node doesn't have any shards left on it. Then stop the `elasticsearch` process and `stop/terminate` the instance.

The commands to check data relocation and shards left can be found in [this article](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/09/replace-node-elasticsearch-cluster.html).

Comment: I do not think this is accurate. At least on v1.7.5 if you exclude a node it will not get NEW shards allocated to it but existing shards are not effected.

Comment: On v1.7.1 excluding a node will affect existing shards.