# On an Elasticsearch cluster, how to have a node not allocate shards on it?

Tags: elasticsearch

On an Elasticsearch n-node cluster, how can you flag a node so not to have shards allocated on that node (for instance when you're putting the node into maintenance)?

I've looked on the documentation but could not find a clear answer.

Comment: Looks like this question was already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268495/how-to-remove-node-from-elasticsearch-cluster-on-runtime-without-down-time

Comment: Thanks, posting an answer anyway as it could be useful for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via this command (e.g. for a cluster node with IP 10.0.0.1):

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

[Source.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-filtering.html)