# how to do cluster auto scaling of elastic search in Kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have set up elastic search using official  [Elastic Search Helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch) I followed below steps

1. Created cluster as below

   `gcloud container clusters create cluster-1 --enable-autoscaling --zone us-central1-c \ --num-nodes 2 \ --min-nodes 1 \ --max-nodes 5`
2. used custom values.yaml for installing elastic search.

`helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f ./values.yaml`

values.yaml

---

```
replicas: 1
# Shrink default JVM heap.
esJavaOpts: "-Xmx128m -Xms128m"

# Allocate smaller chunks of memory per pod.
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "512M"
  limits:
    cpu: "200m"
    memory: "512M"

# Request smaller persistent volumes.
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "standard"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500M

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  path: /
  hosts:
    - elasticsearch.mydomain.com
```

3. Created index and inserted document it elastic db.

   *curl -X PUT "http://elasticsearch.mydomain.com/company" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
   "settings": {
   "number_of_shards": 1,
   "number_of_replicas": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
   "properties": {
   "age": { "type": "integer"},
   "experienceInYears": {"type": "integer" },
   "name": {"type": "text"}
   }
   }
   }
   '*

   *curl -X PUT "http://elasticsearch.mydomain.com/company/_doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
   {
   "name": "John",
   "age" : 30,
   "experienceInYears" : 6
   }
   '*
4. Now I want to send bulk search request to generate load on elastic search pod. So I written below shell script and tried to execute from multiple terminal.

`

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0 # set counter to 0
while true # infinite loop
do   
    curl -X GET "http://elasticsearch.mydomain.com/company/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
        "query" : {
            "match" : { "name" : "John" }
        }
    }' 
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        # curl didn't return 0 - failure
        echo $i
        break # terminate loop
    fi
    i=$(($i+1))  # increment counter
    echo -en "$i        \r"   # display # of requests each iteration
    sleep 0.25  # short pause between requests
done
```

`

5. Now as I am sending bulk request new node should get created (kubernetes cluster auto scaling), but its showing only 2 nodes. May be because cpu limit of 200m is not crossed.

   ```
    kubectl get nodes
    NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
    gke-cluster-1-default-pool-d6891b13-flf9   Ready    <none>   18h   v1.14.10-gke.36
    gke-cluster-1-default-pool-d6891b13-hw2x   Ready    <none>   18h   v1.14.10-gke.36

    kubectl top pods
    NAME                                                              CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
    elasticsearch-master-0                                            160m          371Mi
    ingress-elastic-search-test-ingress-nginx-controller-5c96ctthr2   25m           68Mi
   ```

So how to auto scale elastic search cluster based on load. How to generate load on elastic search pods ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to autoscale elastic search in kubernates based on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710785/how-to-autoscale-elastic-search-in-kubernates-based-on-load)

Comment: You need to cause Elasticsearch to create more replicas.  Scaling _up_ isn't necessarily tricky but scaling _down_ is hard and requires database-specific knowledge, and can take a long time relative to changes in load.

Comment: OK cluster auto scaling is not possible in elastic search ?  You mean to say i should use replicas instead of cluster auto scaling ?

Comment: _Cluster_ autoscaling causes the cluster to create more nodes if pods' resource requests require them.  You need _pod_ autoscaling here, and that's tricky for Elasticsearch (I detail this in the linked question).